# stack fails to build monad-mersenne-random-0.1 package

Tags: haskell, build, dependencies, genetic-algorithm, haskell-stack

I'm trying to install moo stackage and it has the monad-mersenne-random dependency which is giving me the following error. The stack project is fresh created. I tried to add the dependency to the configuration files but it didn't help, and I got the same error.

```
# stack build monad-mersenne-random-0.1
```

gives me:

```
>>/tmp/stack8403/monad-mersenne-random-0.1/Control/Monad/Mersenne/Random.hs:50:10: error:
>>    • No instance for (Applicative Rand)
>>        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
>>    • In the instance declaration for ‘Monad Rand’
>>    |
>> 50 | instance Monad Rand where
>>    |          ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This library is somewhat too old. GHC version from 7.10 or above can't compile it 
If you need to use Random library, you can find another alternative such as [MonadRandom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html)

IMO, GHC 8.4 is too new for production, many libraries haven't supported it yet. You should use GHC 8.2.2 or below